# In Python, how would I iterate over a 2d array for true values?

Tags: python

I have a 2d list of board positions where some are true some are false.

I want to iterate through them all while still having the indexes inside the nest.

aka:

```
for x,y in 2darray:
   if 2darray[x][y] == true: print x,y
```

Comment: What exactly is `2darray`? A list of lists (that is **not an array**) or some sort of `numpy` array?

Answer (score 2):

lets assume the name of 2darray is `x`

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x[i])):
        if x[i][j] == true :
             print (i,j)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

if `l` is your `2darray`, then you can do the following

```
for i, j in [(i, j) for i in xrange(len(l)) for j in xrange(len(l[i]))]:
    if l[i][j]:
        print (i, j)
```